# Trigger a button click from clicking another button in vuetify project?

Tags: vue.js, button, click, vuetify.js, ref

I need clicking on one button to activate a click function on a different button. I expected to be able to use a ref prop on the button to achieve this but instead I get a 'Cannot read property '$refs' of null' console error.

```
<v-btn ref="modalButton" @click="modal">Open Modal</v-btn>
<v-btn @click="this.$refs.modalButton.click()">Click other button</v-btn>
```

Apparently this is because the component [isn't created yet](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-this-refs-key-returns-undefined-when-it-really-is/1226) but I'm truly confused about what that means and how to solve the problem.

Comment: This strikes me as an XY problem. Although you might be able to achieve the effect you described like this `@click="() => { this.$refs.modalButton.$emit('click') }"`

Answer (score 2):

Please note the click has no '()'

```html
<v-btn ref="modalButton" @click="modal">Open Modal</v-btn>
<v-btn @click="$refs.modalButton.$el.click">Click other button</v-btn>
```

Comment: Thanks, man ! This was driving me crazy, for some reason vuetify goes against convention and doesn't make it a function call...

Answer (score 0):

Put "this.$refs.modalButton.click()" into a function - you can't refer to the modalButton that way in the HTML.

Although, if the visibility of your modal is tied to a data property, I don't know why you can't just change the data property directly with both buttons.

Comment: Actually you can, just drop the `this` keyword and make sure the component is already mounted.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do something when another thing happens, try to use something called *event bus*. I solve a lot of problems implementing that.

Here is an example:
https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Btw: If your problem is that the other component has not been created at the render moment, you can solve it calling a function on the *@click* event, then when you click it, you are going to call the function that is going to be called when everything in the DOM has been rendered. At least that is the way that I solve that kind of problems.